# Counting duplicate values

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-formula

I am trying to return the number of times a duplicate value occurs in a column in excel

For instance:

```
Column A  | Column B
12345678  | Return 1
12345678  | Return 2
12345678  | Return 3
23456789  | Return 1
23456789  | Return 2
34567891  | Return 1
```

I should have made my example better, this would be the the dupes are lumped together. In my case they are not.

```
Column A | Column B 

12345678 | Return 1 
23456789 | Return 1 
12345678 | Return 2 
23456789 | Return 2 
34567891 | Return 1 
12345678 | Return 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in Cell B1 and copy it down

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)
```

**Explanation**:

The COUNTIF function counts the number of cells within a range that meet a single criterion that you specify.

If you note that I have kept the first Range constant but affixing $'s `$A$1` and kept the 2nd range as dynamic. As you copy down, the first range will remain a constant and the formula will update to accomodate the left most col A Cell.

**Screenshot (For both Scenarios)**

[image]

Comment: The only issue I am having now is that my data set is about 40000 rows and excel is freaking out when trying to calcuate.

Comment: Yes it will `Freak Out` for so many rows :) but if you give it sometime, it will come back to normal.

Comment: I just tested it, In Excel 2010, it took 21 seconds for 43200 rows