# How to keep only the LAST value of each pair in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Contract No Price
D/019/09    17.85
D/019/09    17.85
D/019/09    17.85
D/019/09    17.85
D/023/09    17.85
D/023/09    17.85
D/026/09    0
D/026/09    0
D/038/11    20.6
D/038/11    20.6
D/038/11    20.6
```

The above is an example data series ... and I will like to keep just the LAST occurence of each unique contract no. In the above example, I would like to only keep D/023/09 17.85, D/026/09 0 and D/038/11 20.6. So there should only be 3 unique values. What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: See this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021609/counting-duplicate-values/16021724#16021724 You will have to modify the formula to suit your needs. This way even if your data is not sorted, it will work.

Comment: Excel > 2003 has the built-in ability to remove duplicate. Before 2007, you can sort the data by Contract No. column, and use eye or a simple formula to remove duplicate.

Comment: If one of the proposed answers solved your problem then you should "Accept" it for the benefit of future readers (and to give some reputation points to the person who took the time to help you).

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment here is another way, which **doesn't need your data to be sorted**. See the example of `D/019/09`

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A2:$A$13,A2)>1,0,B2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No vba needed here... 
Add column C and name it "Check". Insert the following formula in cell C2:

```
=if(A2<>A3,1,0)
```

Than copy that formula till end of your data range. 
Next apply filter for 0 in column C. Delete all rows and you have it.

Your sheet before:

[image]

Your sheet after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Using VBA

[image]

```
Sub sample()

    Dim lastRow As Long, j As Long
    lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

    j = 1
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
            Cells(i, 1).Copy Cells(j, 3)
            Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Copy Cells(j, 4)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```